# How do I get the name of the content type?

Tags: 7, nodes

in Drupal 7, which function do I need to call to get the name of the content type? I have the $node object and I also have the id of the content type if I use `$node->type`. But I need to get the name of the content type set in the system, not the ID as something like 'name_of_the_content_type'. I need it as 'Name of the content type'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try calling this function

[node_type_get_name($node)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_type_get_name/7)

> Returns the node type name of the passed node or node type string.